# Electrical Engineering Math, showing time independence? how?

Tags: basic, math

I have a cheat sheet provided by the teacher about the calculation of the Coherence Time, however I get lost along the way.

There are 2 paths of a signal at:

Path 1: \$\phi_1(t) = 2\pi\frac{vt}{\lambda} = 2\pi f \frac{vt}{c}\$

Path 2: \$\phi_2(t) = 2\pi\frac{2d-vt}{\lambda}=2\pi f\frac{2d-vt}{c}\$

Phase difference at time \$t\$: \$\Delta\phi(t) = \phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t) = 2\pi f\frac{1}{c}(2vt-2d)\$

We want to find the smallest \$\Delta t\$ such that the phase difference of the two phases changes by \$\pi/2\$:

$$T_c(t) =  \arg \underset{\Delta t} \min = \{\Delta t:\Delta\phi(t+\Delta t)-\Delta\phi(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}\}$$

**Showing that \$T_c(t)\$ is actually independent of \$t\$:**

$$\Delta\phi(t+\Delta t)-\Delta\phi(t)=2\pi f\frac{2v}{c}\Delta t=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \Delta t = \frac{1}{8f\frac{v}{c}}=\frac{1}{4(2f\frac{v}{c})}$$

I lose it at the last equation, I can't get what happens there. It would be great if someone could explain me the idea behind the calculation there.

How do we get to this **part**, of the equation above:

$$2\pi f\frac{2v}{c}\Delta t$$

Comment: You can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to put formulas directly in your question, rather than having to link multiple images.

Comment: I went through and converted them, but please double-check to make sure they're right.

Comment: everything seems OK

Answer (score 2):

\$ T_c(t)\$ is indepent from time, because the phase difference does not depend on the moment it is measured.

You already know that $$\Delta\phi(t) = 2\pi f\frac{1}{c}(2vt-2d)$$

Putting \$t+\Delta t\$ in place of \$t\$ in that formula gives you $$\Delta\phi(t+\Delta t)=2\pi f\frac{1}{c}(2v(t+\Delta t)-2d)$$

Now you can calculate the difference: $$\Delta\phi(t+\Delta t)-\Delta\phi(t)=2\pi f\frac{1}{c}(2v(t+\Delta t)-2d)-2\pi f\frac{1}{c}(2vt-2d)=2\pi f\frac{1}{c}(2v(t+\Delta t-t)-2d+2d)=2\pi f\frac{2v}{c}\Delta t$$
, which is the part you were asking for, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: thanks a bunch, the idea behind the calculation makes sense now! Could you please elaborate on one more thing. Why do we put `t+Δt in place of t` in the second formula. For what purpose do we need that step?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. We put it there, because it is the "new" variable of the function \$\Delta\phi(t)\$. Where there was a \$t\$ in the original expression, there has to be a \$t+\Delta t\$ now.

Comment: and what does the `Δt` represent in the function? what does it capture in a real-world scenario? the movement?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm not quite sure about that, and I don't want to lead you astray, so let's wait for someone else to answer this question.

Comment: This may help you though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_time_(communications_systems)